# Average case algorithm analysis using Kolmogorov Incompressibility Method

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

The Incompressibility Method is said to simplify the analysis of algorithms for the average case. From what I understand, this is because there is no need to compute all of the possible combinations of input for that algorithm and then derive an average complexity. Instead, a single incompressible string is taken as the input. As an incompressible string is typical, we can assume that this input can act as an accurate approximation of the average case.

I am lost in regard to actually applying the Incompressibility Method to an algorithm. As an aside, I am not a mathematician, but think that this theory has practical applications in everyday programming.

Ultimately, I would like to learn how I can deduce the average case of any given algorithm, be it trivial or complex. Could somebody please demonstrate to me how the method can be applied to a simple algorithm? For instance, given an input string *S*, store all of the unique characters in *S*, then print each one individually:

```
void uniqueChars(String s) {
    char[] chars = chars[ s.length() ];
    int free_idx = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (! s[i] in chars) {
           chars[free_idx] = s[i];
           free_idx++;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length(); i++) {
        print (chars[i]);
    }
}
```

Only for the sake of argument. I think pseudo-code is sufficient. Assume a linear search for checking whether the array contains an element.

Better algorithms by which the theory can be demonstrated are acceptable, of course.

This question maybe nonsensical and impractical, but I would rather ask than hold misconceptions.

Comment: You might want to check (this paper)[http://homepages.cwi.nl/~paulv/papers/sorting.pdf] for an example of the application of this method. But I have to wonder what your goal is here. Do you have an algorithm whose runtime you want to analyze? As a side note, your provided code may be difficult to analyze because the runtime of `Set.add` depends on the implementation of `Set`.

Comment: This question might be better suited for [Computer Science Stack Exchange](http://cs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: My goal is to learn how to apply the Incompressibility Method for average runtime analysis. This is just a part of personal learning, rather than an immediate requirement.

Comment: murgatroid99, were you referring to this link? http://homepages.cwi.nl/~paulv/course-kc/Tao-AverageNotes.pdf

Comment: Asked a similar question on CS StackExchange: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/35622/26108

Answer (score 0):

reproducing my answer on the [CS.Se question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/35622/average-case-algorithm-analysis-using-kolmogorov-incompressibility-method), for inter-reference purposes

1. **Kolmogorov Complexity** (or **Algorithmic Complexity**) deals with **optimal descriptions of "strings"** (in the general sense of *strings as sequences of symbols*)
2. A string is (sufficiently) **incompressible** or (sufficiently) **algorithmicaly random** if its (algorithmic) description (kolmogorov comlplexity **K**) is **not less than its (literal) size**. In other words **the optimal description of the string, is the string itself**.
3. **Major result of the theory is that most strings are (algorithmicaly) random (or typical)** (which is also related to other areas like Goedel's Theorems, through Chaitin's work)
4. **Kolmogorov Complexity** is related to **Probabilistic (or Shannon) Entropy**, in fact Entropy is an upper bound on KC. And this relates analysis based on descriptive complexity to probabilistic-based analysis. They can be inter-changeable.
5. Sometimes it might be easier to use probabilisrtic analysis, others descriptive complexity (views of the same lets say)

So in the light of the above, assuming an algorithmicaly random input to an algorithm, one asumes the following:

1. The input is **typical**, thus the analysis describes **average-case scenario** (point 3 above)
2. The input **size is related in certain way to its probability** (point 2 above)
3. One can pass **from algorithmic view to probabilistic view** (point 4 above)